# Not able to read Temp Table in spark Sql-Incomplete HDFS URI

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val sparksession=SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local").appname("MyApp").enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate();
val  Df1=sparksession.read.format("csv").option("header","false")
   .option("inferSchema","false").load("file_loc/file_name") 
Df1.createOrReplaceTempView("Temp_Table")
val Df2=sparksession.sql(select * from Temp_Table)
```

I'm trying to read data from a temporary Table, but while selecting data from this table I'm getting an Incomplete HDFS URI issue.

Till `Df1.createOrReplaceTempView("Temp_Table")` line everything is working fine,But when I'm executing last line getting below error messages.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.q1.metadata.HiveException:MetadataException(message:message:MetadataException(message:
Got exception:java.io.IOException Incomplete HDFS URI,no host: hdfs://hostname:port:port/apps/spark/warehouse))


Caused by:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetadataException((message:message:MetadataException(message:
Got exception:java.io.IOException Incomplete HDFS URI,no host: hdfs://hostname:port:port/apps/spark/warehouse))

Caused by:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetadataException:MetadataException((message:message:MetadataException(message:
Got exception:java.io.IOException Incomplete HDFS URI,no host: hdfs://hostname:port:port/apps/spark/warehouse))
```

Checked out all configuration files but couldn't find the port number to be set twice somewhere in configuration files as mentioned in the error message above.Could you please give a hint of what else do I need to check in order to fix this issue? or is there any way to set this value using sparksession?

Comment: Make sure you have env.variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` (or `SPARK_CONF_DIR` ?) pointing to the location of your `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`.

Comment: I would suggest you to run commands in REPL(spark-shell or spark2-shell) for testing the environment connections.
1. Sparksession or Sparkcontext will automatically get created in REPL. Use "sql" to connect to hive metastore to run a query. Provide database as well and keep query in double quotes.
Something similar sc.sql("select count(*) from db.table") or spark.sql("select count(*) from db.table")
If environment is good queries will run smooth.